# Where can I ask questions about economics not related to personal finance?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

From reading this page, I understand that questions about economics not related to personal finance is out of topic here (for example questions about corporate or government finance). Is there any Stack Exchange site where this would be on topic?

Answer (score 5):

https://politics.stackexchange.com/ would be a good place to ask these kind of questions. They have an "economy" tag that should come in handy here.

Answer (score 5):

There was a [StackExchange site for economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics). But alas, it didn't make it out of beta.

Comment: +1 for "alas." It's a good word, yet underutilized.

Comment: I that case, perhaps you'd enjoy http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Economics.SE](http://economics.stackexchange.com/) is up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

The beta https://quant.stackexchange.com/ Should also be a good option, it's about Quantitative Finance, but in order to understand that you'll need to know a lot of economics as well. For questions about Corporate or government Finance I'd opt for this StackExchange.

Comment: What's the purpose of the hidden image you added to your answer?

Comment: @CMPSoares You can ask on [the quant meta](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/) to be sure, but I don't think questions about economics or government/public finance would be on-topic there either. Which tags on the quant site are you referring to? See [this discussion](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/291) for some information about which economics questions they *didn't* want.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea he hidden image is a google analytics beacon created to get info from pages that we edit but aren't completely controlled by us... See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371156/how-do-i-add-real-time-analytics-to-my-q-or-a-on-so/23371157#23371157

Comment: @JohnBensin the tags I'm referring to are economics and   macro-economics, and to the fact that corp and gov finance one of the stronger topics in order to quantify this data, so in my opinion at this moment the most related, thus best to task the question, on SE is quant.SE.

Comment: @CMPSoares Once again, I suggest that you ask on meta.quant.SE *before* directing such questions there, since are opinions are just that, and they have little bearing on what another site chooses to accept.

Comment: Hmm. Do you think adding beacons to individual user posts on a Stack Exchange site is acceptable? Consider: What if we *all* did it? Did you ask at **Meta** Stack Overflow if it is advisable to do so?

Comment: Possible performance reasons aside (which I *think* @ChrisW.Rea is referring to), note that this raises issues of legal consent as well. By using SE sites, I agree to their terms of service that govern how they use information collected from me. I have no such agreement with you or your third-party tracking tool. I [raised the issue on the meta site for the entire network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231608/218097) as well.

Comment: @CMPSoares Also, as mentioned in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192202/218097), this is explicitly disallowed in the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), section 3(e): "**Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that**  ... (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, **surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information**" (my emphasis)