# Why isn't there a small business finance community?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

It seems like one of the most common sources of off-topic questions.

I saw this [post](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2571/se-needs-a-business-finance-and-accounting-community) which looked positive.  What are the costs / needs to get one started?

Answer (score 4):

You need to assemble a group of people willing to kickstart the site, then propose it on https://area51.stackexchange.com/. The full process is described [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) but be aware that you need to get through it quite quickly which won't be possible without [having the community all ready to go](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/changes-to-the-area-51-process-v3-0).